# How can I connect to my virtual machine in a local network?

Tags: webserver, network-bridge

I have installed Ubuntu Server with a webserver on my mac. When I am home I can reach the webserver with network bridge adapter.

But when I go to a local network, I can't see my IP address in Ubuntu with `ifconfig` when I used a dynamic IP (DHCP). If I use a static IP, I see my IP address with `ifconfig` but I can't go to the webserver.

How do I reach the webserver in a local network?

Does I have to change my network settings on my mac, virtualbox or Ubuntu?

I only have Ubuntu server..